# Adding width to <b> tag?

Tags: css

I have a list in which the first word is emboldened, but of course CSS won't let me add a fixed width to the bold tag. Is there a workaround, so I can get Apples, Green and Big to left align? I have no other HTML options.

I have:

• **Fruit:** Apples
   • **Colours:** Green
   • **Size:** Big

```
<script>
ul b {width:200px}  //wont't work
</script>

<ul>
<li><b>Fruit:</b> Apples
<li><b>Colour:</b> Green
<li><b>Size:</b> Big
</ul>
```

Comment: First of all. CSS should be inside <style type="text/css"></style>. Secondly,  what do you mean by `get Apples, Green and Big to left align`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You'd want to add a div to each element and make that width fixed if that's what you desire. You can then style that div to be bold as well.

Comment: You are mixing up styles and scripts

Comment: Should use `<strong>` elements for bold text.

Comment: @IE5Master Not really, he should use CSS.

Comment: @iantresman A simple but *not recommended* way to get the layout you want is to use a table, like so https://jsfiddle.net/feLufvb7/ but if you are developing for modern browsers then there are other, better solutions out there. Right now there are several issues with your code being invalid that need to be resolved before we can help.

Comment: @TylerH sure, you could do both.

Answer (score 6):

The reason why the `<b>` tag is resisting having a width applied is because `<b>` tags are `display:inline` by default.

Making the elements `display:inline-block` will let the width take effect.

```css
ul b {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><b>Fruit:</b> Apples</li>
  <li><b>Colour:</b> Green</li>
  <li><b>Size:</b> Big</li>
</ul>
```

That said, this is **tabular data** and so a `table` would be semantically more correct than an unordered list.

```css
td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Fruit:</td>
    <td>Apples</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Colour:</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size:</td>
    <td>Big</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you can use CSS Tables for much the same effect, just wrap the spare text in a `<span>`.

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: table-row;
}
li * {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><b>Fruit:</b>  <span>Apples</span>
  </li>
  <li><b>Colour:</b>  <span>Green</span>
  </li>
  <li><b>Size:</b>  <span>Big</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```